# How to determine equality between structures and cell arrays

Tags: matlab, comparison, equality

I am confused by why `isequal` is not working in the following two use cases:

```
>> tempStruct = struct('a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3)

tempStruct =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

    a =  1
    b =  2
    c =  3

>> tempCArray = {1 2 3}

tempCArray =
{
  [1,1] =  1
  [1,2] =  2
  [1,3] =  3
}
```

Conceptually in my mind `tempStruct` and `tempCArray` are equal, but

```
>> isequal(tempStruct, tempCArray)

ans = 0
```

Would it be correct to say that this is because the indexing structure of `tempStruct` is different to `tempCArray`? For example:

```
>> tempStruct(2)
error: A(I): index out of bounds; value 2 out of bound 1
>> tempCArray(2)
ans =
{
  [1,1] =  2
}
```

However, then I try to convert `tempStruct` into a cell array:

```
>> struct2cell(tempStruct)

ans =
{
  [1,1] =  1
  [2,1] =  2
  [3,1] =  3
}
```

This now looks to be the same as `tempCArray`. However...

```
>> isequal(struct2cell(tempStruct), tempCArray)

ans = 0
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: They are different types of variables! If you make `tempstruct=struct('a',{1 2 3],'b',2,'c',3)` then `tempstruct.a` will be the same as `{a b c}`, but a structure of cell arrays shouldn't be equal to a cell array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`struct2cell(tempStruct)` and `tempCArray` are not identical.

- In `tempCArray`, The indices are `[1,1], [1,2], [1,3]`.
- In `struct2cell(tempStruct)`, the indices are `[1,1], [2,1], [3,1]`.

These are clearly not the same cell array. `tempCArray` is a row cell vector, while `struct2cell(tempStruct)` is a column cell vector.

If you want the two to be equal, do this:

```
>> isequal(struct2cell(tempStruct)', tempCArray)

ans = 1
```

If you transpose either cell array using `'`, then they will be equal.

Edit:

If you wish to be row/column agnostic, use the following code instead:

```
tempStructCell = struct2cell(tempStruct);    
isequal(tempStructCell(:), tempCArray(:));
```

Comment: is there a way to coerce both types into a something which is row/column agnostic, in the sense that, both of the cell arrays return identical values if linear indexing is used.

Comment: i guess an alternate way of doing this is to find a way of supplying a dimensions argument to `struct2cell`, just like you can for `cell2struct`.

Comment: You can simply use `reshape` to change from row to column and vice versa. For example, `tempStructCell` can be converted from column to row cell vector using: `tempStructCell = reshape(struct2cell(tempStruct), 1, 3);`